# Why I can't reference textbox name vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to add value from array to each textbox.
Here is my code:

```
For i as int32 = 0 To Array.length - 1
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & i + 1).Text = Array(i)
Next
```

When I run above code, I got the NullReferenceException error.
Error Line is:

> Me.Controls("TextBox" & i + 1).Text = Array(i)

I tried another code after searching from the web,

```
For i as int32 = 0 To Array.length - 1
    Dim c as Control() = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i + 1 , True)
    If c.Length = 1 Then
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & i + 1).Text = Array(i)
    End If
Next
```

But it still doesn't work.
Please help me... Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is the value of *i* when the exception occurs? Do you have enough controls?

Comment: An error occured even write one line without looping. Like this:  >Me.Controls("Textbox" & 1).Text = "1234"

Answer (score 1):

Find can return Null (nothing) if it doesn't find a result, which is causing your null reference exception.

As for enumerating/looping over your textbox controls:

Try explicitly looping over them using a foreach on your controls collection

```
    For Each control In Me.Controls
        If control.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
            'Do stuff to control.
        End If
    Next
```

The process you're using now of attempting to map to the name of the control is not going to be very adaptable, especially if someone else comes a long and changes the name of the control.

If there are only a certain set of textboxes you want to update, you could put them in a panel on the form, and use the same method described above to loop through the panel's controls.

Comment: I put all textboxs on panel.I think the problem is not looping.I met NullReference exception, even write just like this: > Me.Controls("Textbox" & 1).Text = "1234"

Comment: OH MY GOD! I can't believe it... I wrote:  >Panel.Controls("Textbox" & 1).Text = "1234" is WORK.. How STUPID I am! Thank you for your answer @DavidY

Comment: It happens :). Enjoy.